# Refactoring service class which communicates with external API

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, spring

Below is the class definition which I created as a POC for some project, at present the class does too much thing and I don't know how to what would be a good design i.e. which object to use as DI etc.

I know that I would like to have some good logging mechanism in case of refactoring things instead of `System.out.println` at the same time I don't want to do over engineering.

**Code:**

```
package com.foobar;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;

import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.Resource;
import com.ResourceTypeEntity;
import com.UserEntity;


import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.UUID;


@Component
public class TicketService
{
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private static final String DEFAULT_RESOURCE_URL  = "http://foo/bar/";

    @Autowired
    public TicketService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate)
    {
      this.restTemplate = restTemplate.build();
    }

    // Rest client to create ticket
    public String createTicket(Principal principal, RRResource rrResource, UUID ticketReference, String subject)
    {
        String delimiter = " , ";
        String stringBuilder = " \n sponser ID==>> " + rrResource.getGtlUserId() +
                " \n Resource Name ==>> " + rrResource.getResourceName() +
                " \n  Resource Reference ==>>  " + rrResource.getTicketReference() +
                " \n Requestor ID ==>> " + principal.getName() +
                " \n  More Info  ==>> " + rrResource.getMoreInfo() +
                " \n  Service Name ==>> " + rrResource.getServiceName() +
                " \n  Project Name ==>> " + rrResource.getProjectName() +
                " \n  Details Of Requested Resource on URL ==>> " + DEFAULT_RESOURCE_URL+ticketReference + delimiter+
                " \n  Request Details ==>> " + rrResource.getResourceRequestCont();

        String content = "queue: foo\nRequestor: " + principal.getName() + "bar\nSubject: " + subject + "\nText: " + stringBuilder;

        String url = "https://foo/REST/1.0/ticket/new?user=x&pass=y";
        String response = sendTicketRequest(content, url);
        return response.trim().substring(27,32);// parsing to get just ticket number out of response
    }

    // Rest client to edit ticket
    public String editTicket(RRResource rrResource, UUID ticketReference) {
        String status = "";
        System.out.println("status --------" + rrResource.getStatus());

        if (rrResource.getStatus().equals("resolved") || rrResource.getStatus().equals("cancelled") ) {
            status = "resolved";
        }

        String s = " \n Status ==>>" + rrResource.getStatus() + " \n  Assign Resource Name ==>> " + rrResource.getResourceName() +
                " \n sponser ID==>>" + rrResource.getGtlUserId() + " \n requestor ID ==>> " + rrResource.getRequestorName() +
                " \n  Requested Resource  content ==>> " + rrResource.getResourceRequestCont() + " \n  More Info  ==>> " + rrResource.getMoreInfo() +
                " \n  Service Name ==>> " + rrResource.getServiceName() + " \n  Project Name ==>> " + rrResource.getProjectName() +
                " \n  Details Of Resource Requested ==>> " + DEFAULT_RESOURCE_URL+ticketReference ;

        String url = "https:foo/REST/1.0/ticket/" + rrResource.getTicketNo() + "/comment?x=rup&pass=y";
        String content = "Action: comment\nStatus: " + status + "\nText: " + s;

        String response = sendTicketRequest(content, url);
        return response;
    }

    private String sendTicketRequest(String content, String url) {
      System.out.println("Ticket Content: " + content);
      MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
      parts.add("content", content);
      HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parts);

      ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
      System.out.println("response.getBody()" + response.getBody());
      return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

PS: I have uglified some name for the sake of project anonymity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the signature of your service, I don't see anything wrong.

The improvements are into the method implementation and specially the way you are buildig your payload.

You can use a `Payload[Builder|Formatter|Writer]` and a `Response[Parser|Reader]` to hide the string building and parsing details.

```
private static final String CREATE_URL = "https://foo/REST/1.0/ticket/new?user=x&pass=y";

public String createTicket(Principal principal, RRResource rrResource, UUID ticketReference, String subject) {
    PayloadBuilder builder = new PayloadBuilder()
        .setQueue("foo")
        .setRequestor(principal)
        .setSubject(subject)
        .addText("sponsor ID", rrResource.getGtlUserId())
        .addText("Resource Name", rrResource.getResourceName())
        .addText("Resource Reference", rrResource.getTicketReference())
        ...;

    TicketResponse response = sendTicketRequest(builder.build(), CREATE_URL);
    return response.getTicketNumber();
}
```

For the logging, it is just a matter of choixe but *Slf4j* seems to be the most used logging library. And it will not add any complexity to your code.